# How to reorganized data in python dataframe by date in tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to reorganized data of a Dataframe with an index of date. Here I show the Dataframe:

```
            H04_PEDRO_MARIN  A13_G_MENOR_POS  E01_TRANCO_BEAS      SUMA
FECHA                                                                  
2017-03-08         0.391776         0.267161         0.080061  0.347222
2017-03-09         0.209277         0.184382         0.076379  0.260761
2017-03-10         0.323770         0.154496         0.077601  0.232097
2017-03-11         0.280073         0.100394         0.078313  0.178707
2017-03-12         0.144533         0.030172         0.080804  0.110976
      ...           ...              ...              ...       ...
2022-11-24         0.000000         0.085510         0.026250  0.111760
2022-11-25         0.000000         0.078270         0.029989  0.108259
2022-11-26         0.000000         0.051454         0.025888  0.077342
2022-11-27         0.000000         0.046259         0.025414  0.071673
2022-11-28         0.000000         0.067865         0.025597  0.093462

[2050 rows x 4 columns]
```

And I'm trying to do a script that reorganized the data by month and year. This is an example of the result that I'd like to get (But I do it manually):

```
            1           2           3          4           5           6          7     ... 31
Enero       0,244675    0,240342    0,193682    0,19523     0,180583    0,149869    0,121562    
Febrero     0,203647    0,179554    0,194301    0,186747    0,193223    0,28368     0,508705    
Marzo       0,300741    0,434384    0,858049    0,802651    0,835299    0,856152    0,888006    
Abril       0,465422    0,413444    0,37834      0,322645   0,389355    0,757714    0,817686    
…
Diciembre
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with helper columns for months and days with aggregate function, e.g. `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(m = df.index.month, d = df.index.day)
         .pivot_table(index='m', columns='d', values='SUMA', aggfunc='sum'))
```

Then if need rename indices:

```
months = ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril',...,'Diciembre']

df1 = df1.rename(dict(enumerate(months, 1)))
```